# Like Unlike toggle button with jQuery's AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

**Goal:** I'm trying to create a button that allows users to like posts on a website, (similar to the way Facebook does it), which would also increment/decrement the number of likes besides the button as well.

**Issue:** Everything works well except in one edge case. If the user has already liked the post, he can unlike it but no longer like it again. It seems like the like/unlike toggle is not working and the browser is only sending an 'unlike' request to the server. If the user has never previously like the image, the like/unlike toggle seems to work just fine.

I make use of the post's data attribute to toggle like/unlike requests by making manipulations on these attributes. I'm currently using PHP through a Laravel framework, and jQuery for my front end manipulations.Below is an example of my code.

**favorite.js file**

```
$(function(){

    $('.favorite-button').click(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        var post_id=$this.data('postId');

        $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
        });



        if($this.data('favoriteId')){
            //decrement the favorite count
            count=$this.siblings('.favorite-count');
            count.html(parseInt(count.html())-1);

            //send ajax request
            var fav_id=$this.data('favoriteId');
            $this.removeData('favoriteId');
            $.ajax({
                url:'/post/'+post_id+'/favorite/'+fav_id,
                type:'DELETE',
                success: function(result){
                    console.log('post was unfavorited');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('error: did not favorite the post.');
                }
            });
        }


        else{
            //update the favorite count
            count=$this.siblings('.favorite-count');
            count.html(parseInt(count.html())+1);

            //send ajax post request
            $.ajax({
                url:'/post/'+post_id+'/favorite',
                type:'POST',
                success: function(result){
                    //update the data attributes
                    $this.data('favoriteId',result['id']);
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log('post was favorited');

                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('error: did not favorite the post.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**The HTML file**

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <span class="marginer">
        @if(Auth::guest() || $post->favorites->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->isEmpty())
            <i  data-post-id="{{ $post->id }}" class="fa fa-heart fa-lg favorite-button"></i>
        @else
            <i  data-favorite-id="{{ Auth::user()->favorites()->where('post_id',$post->id)->first()->id }}" data-post-id="{{ $post->id }}" class="fa fa-heart fa-lg favorite-button"></i>
        @endif

        <span class="favorite-count">{{ $post->favorites->count() }}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Aside from solving my issue, if you think I am not conforming with best practices with this task, please do comment. I'd like to hear your opinion.

Comment: it seems that you don't handle the case properly, i believe if you refresh your page after sending ajax request you will get the desired result and again fall into the case the same problem. You need to handle the update of dom properly after sending AJAX request, the document page is rendered only once from blade engine you need to tell it to rerender that and load new one , or work with JSON responses and update on client-side

Comment: what do you mean not handle the case properly. can you tell me what the right case is by contrasting against my work?.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to make use of jQuery, try to simplify the action of "like/unlike/favorite/count" as much as possible

- Avoid querying from blade templates and just send data to the view

Here is how i would approach this problem instead of letting jQuery do the heavy lifting

HTML/rendered

```
    <button  class='likebutton' data-identifier='1' data-state='liked'>Like</button>
<button class='favoritebutton' data-identifier='1' data-state='favorited'>Favorite</button>
<span class='count counts-1'>123</span>
```

Blade

```
<button  class='likebutton' data-identifier='{{!! Post->ID !!}' data-state='{{!! /*<something to see if user liked this>*/?'liked':'unliked' !!}'>{{!! <something to see if user liked>?'liked':'unliked' !!}</button>
<button class='favoritebutton' data-identifier='{{!! Post->ID !!}' data-state='{{!! /*<something to see if user liked>*/?'favorited':'notfavorited' !!}'>{{!! <something to see if user liked>?'favorited':'notfavorited' !!}</button>
<span class='count counts-{{!! $Post->ID !!}}'>{!! $Post->totallikes !!}</span>
```

JS

```
$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});

function UserLike(_event){
var state = $(_event.target).data('state');
var postID = parseInt($(_event.target).data('identifier'));
console.log('Status => '+$(_event.target).data('state'));
  $.post('/posts/metadata/likes',{
    'postID':postID
  },function(res){
    $(_event.target).data('state',res.state);
    $(_event.target).text(res.text);
    $('.counts-'+postID).text(res.totallikes);
  }).fail(function(){
    /* do something on fail */
  });
}
function UserFavorite(_event){
var postID = parseInt($(_event.target).data('identifier'));
  $.post('/user/metadata/favorites',{
    'postID':postID
  },function(res){
    $(_event.target).data('state',res.state);
    $(_event.target).text(res.text);
  }).fail(function(){
    /* do something on fail */
  });
}

$("body").on('click','.likebutton',function(_event){    UserLike(_event);   });
$("body").on('click','.favoritebutton',function(_event){    UserFavorite(_event);   });
```

PHP

```
// Routes

Route::post('/posts/metadata/likes',function(){
    // auth check
    // handle state/likes
    // ex. response
    // response with json {'state':notliked,'text':'<translated string>','postID':1}
});

Route::post('/user/metadata/favorites',function(){
    // auth check
    // handle state/favorites
    // response with json {'state':favorited,'text':'<translated string>,'postID':1}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest replacing `$this.data('favoriteId');` by `$this.attr("data-favourite-id")` everywhere. It made the difference for me. check this codepen
http://codepen.io/jammer99/pen/PNEMgV

However I have no idea why your solution does not work

Comment: you'r suggestion worked for me. But I still am unsatisfied by the fact that I still do not understand why it did not work. I'm going to leave this question till I see someone give me an explanation to this.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery `data('favoriteId')` does not set the **attribute** `data-favourite`, it's a runtime only setting, it becomes  **property** of the elements, not attrubutes (That's not the same).

**Jquery data can hence not be set by server side code.**

You can read more it in the jquery doc for `.Prop()`:
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

There's an explanation about the difference.
EDIT: Made the bold sentence!

Comment: I know the difference, I have not indicated that I didnt and neither does this answer my question. Why can I not detect the element's data property change in some cases? Thats my question